# What might be a good approach to increase the accuracy of a prediction ML model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a model for predicting which team will win in a popular game based on the characters present on both teams. I have data for around 60k games, where a win/loss is represented by 1/-1 and the data consists of around 100 columns for the individual characters in the game, each row having 0s for the characters not present, 1s for the characters in the friendly team and -1s for the characters in the opposing team. I have trained a simple keras.Sequential() model, but my training accuracy tops at 35% and validation-acc at only 20%. I have tried tweaking various parts of my model but I never seem to get higher accuracy. This is my code:

```
    def build_model():
     model = keras.Sequential([
       layers.Dense(230, activation='relu', input_shape=[len(train_dataframe.keys())]),
       layers.Dense(1,)
     ])

     optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.0008)

     model.compile(loss='mse',
                   optimizer=optimizer,
                   metrics=['accuracy'])
     return model


    EPOCHS = 1000

    history = model.fit(
      X, y,
      epochs=EPOCHS, validation_split = 0.3, verbose=1,
      callbacks=[tfdocs.modeling.EpochDots()])
```

My data looks like this:
Labels:

```
0        1
1        1
2        1
3       -1
4        1
        ..
92644   -1
92645    1
92646    1
92647   -1
92648   -1
Name: -1, Length: 92649, dtype: int64
```

Features:

```
       0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  ...  0.97  0.98  0.99  0.100  0.101  0.102
0      0    0    0    1    0   -1  ...     0     0     0      0      0      0
1      0    0    0    1    0   -1  ...     0     0     0      0      0      0
2      0    0    0    0    0    0  ...     0     0     0      0      0      0
3      0    0    0    0    0   -1  ...     0     0     0      0      0      0
4      0    1    0    0    0    0  ...     0     0     0      0      0     -1
...   ..  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...   ...   ...   ...    ...    ...    ...
92644  1    0    0   -1    0    0  ...     0     0     0      0      0      0
92645  0    0    0    0   -1    0  ...     0     0     0      0      0      0
92646  0    0    0    0    0    0  ...     0     0     0      0      0      0
92647  0    0    0    0    0    1  ...     0     0     0      0      0      0
92648  0   -1    0    0    1    0  ...     0     0     0      0      0      0

[92649 rows x 113 columns]
```

I appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the MeanSquaredError loss instead of the BinaryCrossentropy loss. Since your output is categorical (two options), you should use the BinaryCrossentropy loss.

Comment: Thank you. I tried doing that, but other than changing the loss function values from positive to negative, the accuracy wasn't improved at all. On 200 epochs, I got around 7% for both training and validation accuracy.

Comment: Have you tried changing the metric to BinaryCrossEntropy or BinaryAccuracy? On a high level, lower than 50% accuracy makes no sense here, as there are only two labels. You can get 50% with random guessing. If your model is truly getting 7% accuracy, you can invert its output for 93% accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a big amount of data, which is the most important part in machine learning.

However if you take a look on your model, it has no hidden layers. Try to make your model deeper by adding some layers in between the input and output layer and try with different numbers of neurons for each hidden layer. This may increase your accuracy. I advise you also to check the literature for any special architecture used in this type of data.

Here are some other parameters that may affect your accuracy:

- Weight Initialization.
  -Learning Rate.
- Activation Functions.
- Regularization.
- Optimization and Loss functions.
- Early Stopping.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I have tried using different number of layers with varying numbers of neurons and have found that less layers resulted in better accuracy, though still not more than 30%. I am starting to think that perhaps the features I chose for my model don't correlate with the labels.